# formtastic syntax error when embedding a helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I'm trying to use a little helper to generate some random placeholder text in the title input, but I'm running into trouble.

Here's the view code:

```
<%= form.input :title, :placeholder => "<%= random_title %>".html_safe %>
```

And here is the error I'm receiving:

```
/posts/_form.html.erb:9: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ')'
/posts/_form.html.erb:9: unterminated string meets end of file
```

I'm pretty new to rails, and very new to formtastic. It seems like embedding a call to a helper in the formtastic line is causing this syntax error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`random_title` is a variable, right?

```
<%= form.input :title, :placeholder => random_title.html_safe %>
```

The problem was that you used `<%= %>` within another `<%= %>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= form.input :title, :placeholder => "#{random_title}".html_safe %>
```

this should work.